# Django non-distinct query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

So I am making a query that starts as the following:

```
queryset = FooBar.objects.filter(example__pk__lt=50)
```

where `example` is a foreign key. So this will get all `FooBar` objects that are connected to one of the first fifty `Example`s. But here is my goal:

I want to have this queryset **only include** `FooBar` objects where a different field, lets say `target`, **is not distinct**.

I can do that with the following loop:

```
target_ids = [] #holding a check list for comparison
correct_targets = [] #holding the objects I want to have
for item in queryset: #iteration
    target_ids.append(item.example.pk) #send primary key to check list
    if target_ids.count(item.example.pk) == 2: #check if there has been more than one (if there is more than two I don't send another correct target since I would have already sent it previously)
        correct_targets.append(item) #send correct target
```

I was hoping that there would be a way to get a queryset of these objects from my `queryset` without having to loop through. **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, using [filtering on annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).

```
from django.db.models import Count
qs = FooBar.objects.filter(example__pk__lt=50)
qs = qs.annotate(num_examples=Count('example')).filter(num_examples__gt=1)
```

Comment: from django 3.2 you can use (and it's better to do) alias instead of annotate in examples like this. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#alias)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an aggregate query to get the list of nondistinct items and then use that to filter your other query.

```
nondistinct = Example.objects.values('target').annotate(Count('id')).filter(id__count__gt=1)
Foobar.objects.filter(example__pk__lt=50).filter(example__target__in=[item['target'] for item in nondistinct])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if "reverse distinct" is possible with Django ORM, or not even underlying SQL database.

However the following might be possible

1. Query all items to queryset q1
2. Query distict items to queryset q2
3. Take the difference `qs_not_distict = qs1.exclude(pk__in=qs2)`

Answer (score 0):

Just annotate on any non-dictinct field `value` from your `FK` model:

```
from django.db.models import F
....

qs = FooBar.objects.filter(example__pk__lt=50).annotate(example_target=F(example__target))
```

This query will contain duplicated `FooBar` objects, one object for each new `target` value.